# Prevent other apps from receiving data from the accessory my app is talking to

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

My iOS app is connected and exchanging sensitive data with a BLE accessory, I want the data communication to be secured so I use an encrypted BLE connection (=paired).

But is there a way for my app to be the only app that can receive the data from the accessory?

I want to make sure it is not possible for another app running in the background to receive the data sent by the accessory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Bluetooth will provide access to any apps that are on the device but if you implement your communication using additional authentication or encryption, then it will be harder for other apps to make successful connections to the peripheral.

I think it helps to think of the peripheral as an ssh server. Anyone can open a connection to it but they will be connected only if the correct credentials are provided to the server. Your peripheral should work similarly. The required method for the authentication depends on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. My peripheral will not accept connections from another app. But if my app is connected to the peripheral, nothing seems to prevent another background app from quietly listening to what is sent by the peripheral.

Comment: If the data is encrypted or the connection is refused by the peripheral for unauthenticated centrals, then you are safe. In case of iOS apps as peripherals, you cannot prevent connection or subscription of centrals, but the encryption works well. Real apps use this scheme, e.g. http://www.knocktounlock.com/ add pretty strong encryption to the communication. Adding encryption is not a bad idea anyway as the standard BLE encryption is very weak.

Comment: I see, so basically it is always possible for a sniffer app on the same phone to listen to the incoming traffic from my BLE accessory to my app, so data communication needs a custom encryption layer between my accessory and app. Thanks!